# Por que no ingreso al poner los datos en el login?

Tags: php, pdo, login

sigo viendo el curso de píldoras informáticas de PHP.
En el capítulo 59 se enseña a hacer un login con PDO y POO, al poner los datos de usuario y contraseña que corresponden a la base de datos texto en negrita se debería ingresar a una pantalla que me dijera adelante, sin embargo al poner los datos como corresponden y pulsar el botón login se mantiene en la misma pantalla.

**Link capítulo:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGY-SQtVzJU

**Este es mi código:**

**login.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <h1>Introduce tus datos</h1>
    <form action="comprueba_login.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class = "izq">Login: </td><td class = "der"><input type="text" name="nombre_usuario"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class = "izq">Contraseña: </td><td class = "der" ><input type="password" name"contrasenia_usuario"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name ="enviar" value="LOGIN"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**comprueba_login.php**

```
    <?php
    
        try{
            
            $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas" , "root" , "");
            
            $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
            $query="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO = :NOMBRE_USUARIO AND CONTRASENIA_USUARIO = :CONTRASENIA_USUARIO";
            //CONSULTA PREPARADA CON MARCADORES
            $resultado=$base->prepare($query);
            
            $nombre_usuario = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["nombre_usuario"]));
            
            $contrasenia_usuario = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contrasenia_usuario"]));
            
            $resultado->bindValue(":NOMBRE_USUARIO",$nombre_usuario);
            
            $resultado->bindValue(":CONTRASENIA_USUARIO",$contrasenia_usuario);
            
            $resultado->execute();
            
            $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount();
            
            
            if($numero_registro!=0){
                
                echo "<h2>Adelante</h2>";
                
            }else{
                
                header("location:login.php");
                
            }
            
            
        }catch(Exception $e){
            
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            
        }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: te queda en la pantalla de login, pero te borra el contenido de los inputs?

Comment: Pongo la variable de esta forma: echo "$numero_registro"; pero no aparece nada. Sigue el formulario al volver al cargar. No se porque no avanza a la otra pantalla comprueba_login.php

Comment: @IvanDinamarcaCastro Una pregunta ya tienes en la Base de datos una tabla con los usuarios que tendrán el acceso a tu sistema ?

Comment: Si, base de datos phpmyadmin llamada pruebas, tabla llamada usuarios_pass e ingreso los datos en nombre_usuario IVAN y contrasenia_usuario 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes no tiene nada que ver con la base de datos, el problema esta en tu etiqueta:

```
 <td class = "izq">Contraseña: </td><td class = "der" ><input type="password" name"contrasenia_usuario"></td>
```

el error se encuentra aqui:

```
name"contrasenia_usuario"
```

y debe ser:

```
name="contrasenia_usuario"
```

o sea te falto el signo: `=`

> Por cierto, si tu nombre de usuario esta en mayúsculas, debes escribirlo
> en mayúscula, tal como, lo registraste en la DB. Esto para evitar
> dolores de cabeza

Comment: Así es. Diste en el clavo. Saludos.